# Dynamic content inside Ajax's "Update" tag

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to update dynamically the content of the clicked tab inside a tabView  in Primefaces. I am trying to simulate what I have inside the listener tag for my ajax, I know this doesn't work when clicking a tab because the EL inside the listener tag has already been evaluated to a string. The question, is there any way to do this?? Thanks for your help.

```
<p:tabView id="tv1" widgetVar="wv1" activeIndex="1">

      <p:ajax event="tabChange"
              listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"
              update="#{bean.updatedTabID}"/>

      <p:tab title="tab1">
         <p:dataTable id="dtTab1">... </p:dataTable>
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab title="tab2">
         <p:dataTable id="dtTab2">... </p:dataTable>
      </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Backing bean

```
String updatedTab

public String updatedTabID(){
    return updatedTab;
}

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    Tab activeTab = event.getTab();
    String activeTabTitle = activeTab.getTitle();        

    if(activeTabTitle.equals("tab1")){
       updatedTab=":tv1:dtTable1";
       // update dataTable1 collection

    }else if(activeTabTitle.equals("tab2")){
       updatedTab=":tv1:dtTable2";
       // update dataTable2 collection
    }
}
```

Comment: The same principles in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14779852/1530938) will work for your need

Comment: Thanks kolossus, that did the job.