# Update PrimeFaces dataTable from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use schedule(Timer) in bean which update variable when employees enrolling which get data from fingerprint device.  I need to update component in jsf  from backing bean when variable in bean updated. I try to use primefaces poll component but it update component every time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you'll be calling a Java method using Listener from Fingerprint device API, and from ManagedBean you can update any Primefaces Component using [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html).

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("ID_OF_YOUR_DATATABLE")
```

Comment: In Primefaces 7.0 (2019) is import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("Element ID");

Answer (score 2):

There's already a component in **Primefaces**, as you can see : [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml).

> RequestContext is a feature with various handy utilities.
>
> Update component(s) programmatically. Execute javascript from beans.
>   Add ajax callback parameters. ScrollTo a specific component after ajax
>   update.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779852/primefaces-ajax-update-different-panels-according-to-backbean-result) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

It has changed from primefaces 7.0

```html
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("elementJS");
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem with primefaces push component.

java code is:

```
 PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
  pushContext.push("/finger", "Pressed");
```

in jsf:

```
<p:socket channel="/finger" onMessage="clearCookies" />
```

"clearCookies" is remoteCommand function which update my dataTable.

Comment: I had also followed this approach. Invoking `remoteCommand`'s javascript function on `onMessage` of `p:socket`.